# Подскажите реализацию элемента в андроид

Tags: android, xml

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста реализацию элемента прокручиваемого списка с выбранным одним элементом.? Как например реализовано при выборе времени в приложении часы? Может это спиннер?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [NumberPicker](https://medium.com/@sc71/android-numberpickers-3ef535c45487) API Android. Кастомная реализация [NumberPicker](https://github.com/BorealisAgency/NumberPicker). Больше [вариантов реализаций](https://github.com/search?q=android+numberpicker)

Comment: Есть ли возможность реализации с текстом?